# Generic parameter 'C' could not be inferred

Tags: dictionary, swiftui

I have a Data class as follows:

```
    class Data: Hashable, Equatable {
        var id: Int = 0
        var name: String = ""
        var date: Date = Date()
        var paymentStatus: Bool = false
    
        static func == (lhs: Data, rhs: Data) -> Bool {
            return lhs.id ==    
        }
    
        func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
            hasher.combine(id)
        }
    }

    var data1: Data {
        let data = Data()
        data.id = 1
        data.name = "John"
        data.date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: DateComponents(day: -6), to: Date())!
        data.paymentStatus = true
        return data
    }

var data2: Data {
    let data = Data()
    data.id = 2
    data.name = "Peter"
    data.date = Date()
    data.paymentStatus = false
    return data
}
```

I’m trying to display the data in sections as follows:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var data: [Data] = [data1, data2] 
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(groupByDate(data), id: \.self) { studentsInMonth in 
                Section(header:Text(Date(), style: .date)) {
                    ForEach(data, id:\.self) { item in 
                        HStack {
                            Text(item.name)
                            padding()
                            Text(item.date, style: .time)
                            if(item.paymentStatus == false) {
                                Image(systemName: "person.fill.questionmark")
                                    .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                            } else {
                                Image(systemName: "banknote")
                                    .foregroundColor(Color.green)
                            }
                        }
                    } // ForEach ends here... 
                } // section ends here
            } // ForEach ends here
        } // List ends here
    }
}

func groupByDate(_ data: [Data]) -> [Date: [Data]] {
    let empty: [Date: [Data]] = [:]
    return data.reduce(into: empty) { acc, cur in
        let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month], from: cur.date)
        let date = Calendar.current.date(from: components)!
        let existing = acc[date] ?? []
        acc[date] = existing + [cur]
    }
}
```

Not sure what mistake I’m making, but its throwing two errors:

1. Cannot convert value of type ‘[Date:[Data]]’ to expected argument type
2. Generic parameter ‘C’ could not be inferred

Appreciate any help

Comment: You are also missing a dot before `padding()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, you're trying to iterate through a `Dictionary` using `ForEach`, which doesn't work -- `ForEach` expects a `RandomAccessCollection`, which is most often, an `Array`.

Instead, you can iterate over just the keys of the `Dictionary`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var data: [Data] = [data1, data2]
    
    var body: some View {
        let grouped = groupByDate(data)
        List {
            ForEach(Array(grouped.keys), id: \.self) { key in
                let studentsInMonth = grouped[key]!
                Section(header:Text(key, style: .date)) {
                    ForEach(studentsInMonth, id:\.self) { item in
                        HStack {
                            Text(item.name)
                            padding()
                            Text(item.date, style: .time)
                            if(item.paymentStatus == false) {
                                Image(systemName: "person.fill.questionmark")
                                    .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                            } else {
                                Image(systemName: "banknote")
                                    .foregroundColor(Color.green)
                            }
                        }
                    } // ForEach ends here...
                } // section ends here
            } // ForEach ends here
        } // List ends here
    }
}
```

Although the above works, I'd consider refactoring your `groupByDate` function so that it returns an `Array` directly instead of having to go through the above transformations.

Also, unrelated to your question, but right now, in your header, you're displaying a date -- you get just the `year` and `month`, but then display it as a full date, so the header says "January 1, 2022" for all the January dates. You probably want to refactor this to just show the month and year.